# Capture one suffix containing known substring when multiple matching prefixes (without known substring) found

Tags: regex, regex-group, re2, text-capture

Given an input of multiple string, some containing the prefix `is:`, I need to capture one instance of the substring "Foo" or "Bar" following the `is:` prefix regardless of how many times `is:Foo`/`is:Bar` or `is:Baz`/`is:Xyzzy` appear.

Using the following regex: `.*is:\b([Foo|Bar]*)\b.*`

And using the following examples of test input lines with matches:

```
"is:Baz is:Foo FooBar"          # Captures "Foo"
"is:Foo FooBar is:Bar"          # Captures "Bar"
"is:Bar FooBar FooBaz Baz"      # Captures "Bar"
"FooBar is:Bar FooBaz"          # Captures "Bar"
"FooBar is:Xyzzy is:Foo"        # Captures "Foo
"is:Baz FooBar is:Foo"          # Captures "Foo"
"FooBar is:Foo is:Xyzzy"        # No capture
```

In the final line I want to also capture `is:Foo`, but the capture is thrown off by `is:Xyzzy`. This isn't an exhaustive list of possible test cases but it illustrates to problem I'm coming up against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the pattern using a grouping without the `[` and `]` that denotes a character class.

You don't need a word boundary here `:\b` as it is implicit due to the following alternation of `(Foo|Bar)`

You can append a word boundary before `\bis`

```
.*\bis:(Foo|Bar)\b.*
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/lxC896/1).